# How to extract PDF from memory buffer

Tags: pdf, memory, extract, foxit

an application uses FoxitPDF SDK to load a pdf .

It uses the following function to load the pdf from memory and display.

http://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals/DLL311/group___f_p_d_f_v_i_e_w.html#gafc1bfd72af5ccb5d6b9112c50fe90834

How can we extract the pdf out from the memory to .pdf file.

Comment: `data_buf` *- Pointer to a buffer containing the PDF document.* `size` *- Number of bytes in the PDF document.* - thus, simply take `size` many bytes starting at `data_buf`.